# c algorithm - question

Tags: c, algorithm

What kind of algorithm should i use to calculate 2^n . . Where n is always greater than 100 . . Suggest a good algorithm using c :)

Comment: With what results? `double` or `bigint`?

Comment: It must be more a question about correct data type, not the algorithm

Answer (score 10):

To calculate 2^n with log(n) complexity you can do the following (assuming type can store the result we get):

```
type result = 1;
type temp = 2;

while (n){
   if (n%2)
     result *= temp;
   temp *= temp;
   n/=2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably you should search for algorithm for conversion from binary to decimal in bigint format. Note that your number in binary system will be represented as

```
100...00 // n - 1 zeros
```

Doing one conversion between binary to decimal will be much faster then performing `log(n)` multiplications of `bigint`.

If you really want to use many multiplications read about [Karatsuba Multiplication](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KaratsubaMultiplication.html)

EDIT: [This](http://www.exploringbinary.com/a-simple-c-program-that-prints-2098-powers-of-two/) blog post presents a way to calculate 2^1023 using one double-precision floating-point variable

Comment: I've just finished coding up a long-multiplication function for large integers; I wish I'd heard of Karatsuba Multiplication before.

Comment: The binary to decimal conversion, under the covers, is almost certainly going to be of O(n). It would be general purpose, so it wouldn't know per se that only 1 bit was set. Even if it did know, it couldn't compute a single power of two more efficiently than @Vladimir's O(log(n)) solution (which, BTW, is called "successive squaring" or "binary exponentiation").

Comment: regarding my program to compute 2^1023 (thanks for the reference), it is of O(n). It computes a sequence of powers of two, not an individual power of two. However, it does imply that @Vladimir 's algorithm will work to up to 2^1023 without using bigints!

Comment: @Rick: I had used "successive squaring" technique many times, but I make suggestion that probably performing base conversion can be done quicker than simple multiplication performed n-times. I will have to verify my hipotesis. BTW you won't probably feel much difference between O(n) and O(log(n)) when n = 1023 :)

Comment: You did say "Doing one conversion between binary to decimal will be much faster then performing log(n) multiplications of bigint". I was only responding to that.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you want to print the result in base 2, or base 16 - the solution is strightforward. The real problem is converting the result to base 10 representation.

Since n>100 and you probably want an exact answer, and maby you would also like to manipulate the answer, you should consider using an [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library.

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is a good implementation for such library. According to [GMP documentation](http://gmplib.org/gmp-man-5.0.1.pdf), GMP implements several multiplication algrorithms according to operand size (see section 16.1 for a nice overview of those algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

Start by figuring out what format your output needs to be in.  Then figure out what kind of data structure you can store information in, which you could also use to generate that kind of output.  I'm guessing you will need an array of some sort in order to store numbers that large. Then you need to figure out how to convert the contents of that array to the output format you need.  And, of course, you need to figure out how to perform the math itself 2^n.  figure out what 2^n means in terms of its representation in binary.  Of course if your output is in binary, octal or Hex, the solution is quite simple.  If it's in decimal, you'll probably want your array to be a representation of decimal digits and implement some code that can multiple a decimal digits number by 2 kind of the same way humans do (if you ca't think of a better answer).

Answer (score 2):

mhmh - how about
   leftShift(2, n-1)
using some bignum package ?

Answer (score 2):

If `n` has a reasonable upper bound and speed is a critical factor, precalculate the values and store them in a lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is an integer, simply left shift `1` `n` times. For large `n`, ordinary shift operations will not suffice.

If `n` is a double, use `exp2(n)` from `math.h`.